# What is the probability $P(X = Y)$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are independent, circularly symmetric Gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

For the random variable x and y mean is zero and variance is $1$.

### Efforts

I tried to find its solution by the following technique i.e.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\overline{x}} e^{\frac{-x}{\overline{x}}} \times \frac{1}{\overline{y}} e^{\frac{-y}{\overline{y}}} dx \ dy$$
where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the respective means of $x,y$.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If by "circularly symmetric", you mean that $p(x,y)$ depends only on $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then $x$ and $y$ are not independent.

Comment: Hi what have you tried so far ?

Comment: for both the random variables mean is zero and variance is 1.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Sir, I tried to find its solution by following technique i.e. $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\overline{x}} e^{\frac{-x}{\overline{x}}} \times \frac{1}{\overline{y}} e^{\frac{-y}{\overline{y}}} dx \ dy$ where $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ are mean of x and y respectively.

Comment: i have edited your question, please check if there's anything to add

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Thank you Sir, now the question gives much more clarity.

Comment: @Acccumulation : What makes you think they're not independent? If the joint density is $\text{constant} \times e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} = \text{constant} \times e^{-x^2/2} e^{-y^2/2},$ then they are independent. $\qquad$

Comment: @Acccumulation : $\ldots\,$and one should not use the same symbol, $x,$ nor $y,$ to refer both to the random variable and to the argument to its density function.